# How can I override the total sum of the EXTJS summary?

Tags: extjs4, grouping, paging, summary

I am using EXTJS 4.2.1 and my application has a grid including paging, the grouping summary and the summary feature. I want to override the sum of the summary feature, because it should display the grand total sum of the whole data set and not only for the current displayed page.
Is that possible to override the summary feature to do so?

Thanky you very much for every advice in advance. :-)

Comment: You would have to count the summary server-side and send it to client and use the summary feature simply for showing the data. I can't tell you more until I know what summary feature are you using.

Comment: I am using the normal summary feature for grids. And I want to sum up the two columns, but the paging mechanism doesn't seem to summerize the sum of the different pages.... It sums only the columns on the current page and rests on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `summaryRenderer` in column configuration. It is an undocummented feature of ExtJS allowing you to show custom data in your summary row.

You will have to summarize the data server-side and send them to client where you will access it in the `summaryRenderer`.

Like so:

```
columns: {
    items: [
        {
            text: "Column A",
            dataIndex: "field_A",
            summaryRenderer: function( value, summaryData, dataIndex ) {
                var grid = this;

                // Get the value here and return it
                var result = functionToGetValue( grid );

                return result;
            }
        },
        // ...
    }
]
```

The `functionToGetValue` is the place where you pass the summarization value you sent to your client from server.

How you do that depens on your code. You have access to store via `grid.getStore()`.

It is possible to add the summary data to each record and then simply use `store.getAt(0).get( 'summaryValue' )`, it is kind of wasteful, but it is simple and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marthy. I will try it this tomorrow and give you a feedback.

Comment: So, how did it go?

Comment: It works fine except one thing... After using paging the summarized values from the previous pages aren't sumed... The amounts are summed only for the current page. Do you have an advice for the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. This is the original problem, isn't it? Are you counting the summary on server as my answer stated, and just sending the summary value to the client?

Comment: The problem is, that if i summarize it on server side, I am summarizing over all data and not only for the first page. I have to find out, how to summarize only the first page. By the way it is an Oracle database. But you have solved my problem. Thanks :-)